# Как переписать данный код JS на JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for (let i = 0; i < menuLinks.length; i++) {
    mobileLink[i].addEventListener('click', event => {
      mobile.classList.add('hide');
      body.classList.remove('hidden');
      burgerMenu.classList.remove('menu-burger--active');
      sections.forEach(section => {
        section.classList.add('hide');
      });
      if (sections[i].classList.contains('hide')) {
        sections[i].classList.remove('hide');
      }
    });
    menuLinks[i].addEventListener('click', event => {
      sections.forEach(section => {
        section.classList.add('hide');
      });
      if (sections[i].classList.contains('hide')) {
        sections[i].classList.remove('hide');
      }
    });
  }
```

Если вместо `document.querySelectorAll` брать через `$('.class');`, то при переборе массива в цикле кидает ошибку.

Comment: menuLinks, mobileLink, sections - как они полчены? Все querySelectorAll?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME да, все через document.querySelector, document,querySelectorAll

Comment: а в чем смысл переписывать?

Answer (score 3):

`querySelectorAll` возвращает не массив: Это коллекция [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList), у которого в современных браузерах есть встроенный метод `forEach`

`$('.class')` дает специальный jQuery-объект со встроенными методами, среди которых тоже нет forEach. В jQuery [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Перевод:

```
let $mobileLinks = $(".mobileLink"); // замените на названия своих классов.
let $menuLinks = $(".menuLink");
let $sections = $(".section");

let $body = $("body");
let $mobile = $(".mobile").eq(0);
let $burgerMenu = $(".burgerMenu").eq(0);
// собирает все элементы, берет первый, а-ля querySelector (хотя он
  // изначально берет только первый элемент и останавливается)

$menuLinks.each(function(i) {

  $menuLinks.eq(i).on("click", function() {
    $sections.addClass('hide');    // Убирает 'hide' у всех,
    $sections.eq(i).removeClass("hide"); // Добавляет `i`-тому элементу.
  });

  $mobileLinks.eq(i).on("click", function() {
    $mobile.addClass("hide");
    $body.removeClass("hidden");
    $burgerMenu.removeClass("menu-burger--active");
    
    $sections.addClass("hide");
    $sections.eq(i).removeClass("hide");
  });

});
```

Внутри each, `$menuLinks.eq(i)` можно заменить на `$(this)`. Но первый вариант симметричнее)